# Angularjs rest call using $http not working with Spring RestController rest apis

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a spring `RestController` which I have developed using SpringBoot.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myRoot")
public class MyRestController {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/add/{myItem}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody void addMyItem(@PathVariable("myItem") String myItem){
        myService.addMyItem(myItem);
    }
}
```

My Spring Boot class containing `main` method is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.mypackage"})
public class MyRestApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyRestApp .class, args);
}
}
```

When I compile the project run the generated Jar as Java Application in Eclipse, the console shows:

```
2017-03-17 22:33:14.363  INFO 2292 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-17 22:33:14.371  INFO 2292 --- [           main] o.n.todo.springboot.SuperrDuperrRestApp  : Started MyRestApp in 7.056 seconds (JVM running for 7.837)
```

Making a post call of `http://localhost:8080/MyRestApi/myRoot/add/myItem` on Postman on Chrome returns success (200 OK).

This means my rest api is correctly exposed and up and running.

I am trying to call above rest URI from my AngularJs 1 app as below:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module("MyFirstAngularRestApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);

function myCtrl($http){
  console.log("myCtrl");

  var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/MyRestApi/';

  this.AddItem = function(newItem){
  console.log("AddItem");
  console.log(newItem);

  $http.post(this.REST_SERVICE_URI + 'myRoot/add/' + newItem).then(function(response){
        console.log("success");
    });
  }
 }
```

However, this is not working. I am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/myDevelopment/Angular/MyAngularApp/undefinedtoDo/add/ReadABook. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"undefinedtoDo/addItem/Read a Book","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

I am absolutely new to AngularJs 1, so not able to understand why my rest call is not working. What am I missing?

My AngularJs project is on a different location on my laptop drive and my eclipse workspace is a different directory. But I believe this should not be of importance.

I will really appreciate, If someone can guide me how to resolve this error. Request to answer in as much detail as possible as I am new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a cross-origin error, try annotating your controller with **@CrossOrigin**, it will allow your application to call the API. Using the annotation, you can specify domains (origin) and methods (PUT, GET, POST, etc). See more: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html

If you want to define the domain you want to allow, use the following piece of code in a configuration class. In this case, you don't need to annotate all your controllers:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**/*").allowedOrigins("locahost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular application and server are running on different origins and browsers generally, do not support that due to [same-origin policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

You can easily fix this by annotating your controller or a specific method, if you want with **@CrossOrigin** annotation as follows :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", methods = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE,
    RequestMethod.PUT })
```

As you can see, you can be specific with the host or supported http methods etc.